# Play Framework templates

Tags: java, scala, templates, playframework-2.0

I've recently started playing with Play Framework and I was wondering: is there a way to write my templates using not Scala but Java?

E.g. this link http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaGuide3 provieds great tutorial to start with, but some Scala code makes it really hard for me to understand almost anything...

I mean, I could learn that much but it would be amazing if it's possible to write all in Java

Comment: TIP: don't think about templates as about Scala, but just _some_ templating syntax, you'll get it in several hours

Comment: My first experience with Scala was Play templates. They're really quite easy to pick up. As a template language, it's really not harder to learn than Freemarker, JSTL or Scalate.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use Freemarker as a template language.

https://github.com/guillaumebort/play2-freemarker-demo

Answer (score 0):

You can effectively use Freemarker and you can also don't use server side compiled template :

- Create Rest API
- Put html template in public directory
- Use javascript for populate view (html)

For structure your application, Angular could be a good solution.

Comment: But not need to know scala for use scala template